# Being updated that a member variable has been set/has changed

Tags: c++, notifications, state

I have a quite huge/involved class `C` (quite difficult to refactor as no one ever tried to do so since 15 years, so that things have piled up to the rafters, plus bad design) containing an `int` member variable called let's say `m_Toto`. Whenever you instantiate an object from `C`, you pass by an `init()` member function that sets a lot of things, among them it sets `m_Toto` to `0`. After some data member have been set and used, on can calculate the value that `m_Toto` is going to have. This value will be central to everything else the class does.

Now, bad naming set aside, `m_Toto` is calculated for the first time through the call of the `int C::GetToto()`, which has this structure :

```
int C::GetToto()
{
    if (m_Toto != 0)
        return m_Toto ;
    // else
    // we calculate m_Toto thx to a lot of data etc
}
```

Whenever we need `m_Toto`'s value, we call `GetToto()`, who checks that `m_Toto` is initialized (*i.e.* is non zero), and returns, the "real" calculation being done the first time only.

My problem is the following. I have a state of `C` that is defined by a `bool` member variable `m_IsBlah`, and which should be determined thx to the value of `m_Toto`.

How could I do to be sure, in a elegant way, to be sure that `m_IsBlah` will be calculated only the first time `m_Toto` is calculated, and only then, without resorting to ugly `if`'s of the above kind ? Or is it too much overkill ?

Answer (score 0):

As always with C++, use `class`es to capture abstractions. Have the class as a member of `C` contructed in its constructor and reports if and when `IsBlah` is set and if so to what.